# GPS coordinates in degrees to calculate distances

Tags: iphone, math, gps, coordinates, measurement

On the iPhone, I get the user's location in decimal degrees, for example: latitude 39.470920 and longitude = -0.373192; That's point A.

I need to create a line with another GPS coordinate, also in decimal degrees, point B. Then, calculate the distance (perpendicular) between the line from A to B and another point C.

The problem is I get confused with the values in degrees. I would like to have the result in meters. What's the conversion needed? How will the final formula to compute this look like?

Answer (score 10):

use - (CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFrom:(const CLLocation *)location

```
firstLongitude = 30.0;
firstLatitude = 30.0;

secondLongitude = 40.0;
secondLatitude = 40.0;

CLLocation *firstLoc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:firstLatitude longitude: firstLongitude];
CLLocation *secondLoc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:secondLatitude longitude: secondLongitude];

double distanceInMeters = [firstLoc getDistanceFrom: secondLoc];
```

Comment: Voted up... I missed that this was an iPhone question. Using CoreLocation calls is definitely the way to go.

Comment: nice answer, but doesn't solve the problem: he still has to determine the point on the connecting line between A and B of which he wants to compute the distance from C, and that's the hard part

Comment: @Christoph: I was gonna make a similar comment and also suggest (as you did) to solve the problem (or parts of it at least) in 3-space.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is non-trivial: On a spheroid, there might even be more than one line perpendicular to AB through C.

If the distances are small, you might get away with the euclidian approximation

```
Δx = R·cosα·Δλ
Δy = r·Δφ

r = b²/√(b² + (a² - b²)·cos²φ)
R·cosα = a²/√(a² + b²·tan²φ)
```

with latitude `φ`, longitude `λ`, semimajor axis `a` and semiminor axis `b`; in spherical approximation `a = b`. The `φ` in the formulae for `r` and `R·cosα` has to be some sort of mean value.

[metric on spheroid http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/3620/spheroid.gif](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/3620/spheroid.gif)

An approach which might give better results would be to solve the problem in 3-space (and not on the surface of the spheroid) and get the arc length associated with the connecting line.

To do this, you need to know how to convert from geographical coordinates with normal angle `φ` to cartesian coordinates

```
z = b²·sinφ/√(a²·cos²φ + b²·sin²φ)
r = a²·cosφ/√(a²·cos²φ + b²·sin²φ)
x = r·cosλ
y = r·sinλ
```

and from geocentrical coordinates with polar angle `α` to cartesian coordinates

```
z = a·b·sinα/√(a²·sin²α + b²·cos²α)
r = a·b·cosα/√(a²·sin²α + b²·cos²α)
x = r·cosλ
y = r·sinλ
```

Note that the `r` in these formulae is different from the one in the picture above.

Let `A`, `B`, `C` be the vectors in euclidian space corresponding to your points on the spheroid's surface. The foot of perpendicular `F` is given by

```
F = 1/|B-A|² · (<B-A,C-A>·B - <B-A,C-B>·A)
```

where `<,>` is the scalar product and `|·|` the norm.

Now, we have to determine the point `F'` on the spheroid's surface corresponding to `F`, which means we'll have to compute

```
λ' = atan2(y,x)
α' = arctan(z/√(x² + y²))
```

and then convert these back to cartesian coordinates.

The length of the secant is given by

```
d = |F'- C|
```

The corresponding arc length in spherical approximation is

```
s = R·β
```

where `β` is the angle between `F'` and `C`, ie

```
β = arccos(cosβ) = arccos(<F',C>/(|F'|·|C|))
```

and `R` is either the mean radius given by

```
R = ³√(a²·b)
```

or using the cosine rule for a better value for small distances

```
R = d/√(2·(1 - cosβ))
```

Comment: turns out the euclidean approximation is wrong - `r`, the radius of curvature in meridian, doesn't end at the equatorial plane; the second algorithm should be fine...

Comment: hi @Christoph, can you help me with me question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72983832/how-get-distance-in-degrees-to-calculate-buffers-in-athena

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [geographical distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance) and [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) articles on wikipedia. They provide the formulas you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM) coordinate system and terms easting and northing. The basic idea is to convert GPS coordinates (which are in WGS84 coordinate system) to distance from some point - in case of UTM northing is a distance from the equator and easting is distance from one selected meridian. Using this conversion you'll be able to get quite good approximation of real distance between two points.

Comment: +1. If the original poster wants the end result in metre precision then they had better use coordinates from a more accurate projection than a sphere.

Answer (score 1):

For latitude, one degree is around 1852 meters.

The conversion for Longitude depends on the latitude. The math is a little fuzzy for me, but I seem to remember it being something like COS(latitude * PI / 180) * 1852

Comment: i think you mean 1852 km (i.e. 1,852,000 m)

Comment: Neither of those make sense. One *minute* of latitude is about 1852 metres (one nautical mile). One ° latitude is ~60 NM or ~111 km (~20000/180). 1852 km is 1000 NM, or ~16⅔°.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, Ahruman. I simply knew the original value could  not possibly be right, and assumed it was a problem with the unit, but never actually checked which unit.

Answer (score 1):

As Christoph suggested, the harder part of the problem is probably better solved in 3-space.

My suggested solution (sorry, no code) - it assumes a spherical earth:

- express A,B,C as vectors from earth center, E
- find vectors orthogonal to both EA (vector from E to A) and EB (there should be two), via vector [cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html)
- determine the smallest angle between the two orthogonal vectors and EC, via [dot product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotProduct.html)
- subtract from 90 deg
- the resulting angle is the 'latitude' of C if we rotate the coordinate system such that A and B are on the equator, which can easily be converted to distance (see richardtallent's answer)